# How can I write an SQL query that (1) groups by average and (2) adds a new column with the average of the entire dataset

Tags: sql

I've been breaking my head over this for the past day and I cant seem to figure it out. Maybe it's not possible? (please let me know if that's the case).

Basically I'm trying to get the average sales of each location and then add an extra column that shows me the average sales of the entire dataset. The two requirements separately are easy, the problem is combining them.

Current data set -

| Location | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 5 |
| France | 10 |
| India | 15 |
| USA | 3 |
| France | 4 |
| India | 5 |

What I would like to produce -

| Location | Avg.Sales | Dataset_Avg. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 4 | 7 |
| France | 7 | 7 |
| India | 10 | 7 |

**-- Step 1 trying to get the data without combining (works perfectly)**

-- Gives you the avg sales by location

```
SELECT location_id, AVG(sales)
FROM table
WHERE (date > '01/01/2023')
GROUP BY location_id;
```

-- Window function that gives you the total avg time to fill (for all

```
SELECT location_id, AVG(sales) OVER () AS total_avg
FROM table
WHERE (date > '01/01/2023');
```

**-- Step 2 trying to combine - this is where I'm struggling**

-- Tried combining Aggregate and Window function (not possible)

```
SELECT location_id, AVG(sales) AS location_avg, AVG(sales) OVER () AS total_avg
FROM table
WHERE (date > '01/01/2023');
```

-- Create a CTE with time to fill by location and then join to window function?
-- 2 issues here (1) you cant call a window function in the CTE (a. doesnt work) and 2nd problem is you cant have a where clause in the 2nd function

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT location_id AS CTE_location_id, AVG(sales) AS avg_sales_by_location
FROM table
WHERE (date > '01/01/2023')
GROUP BY CTE_location_id
)

SELECT a.location_id, a.(AVG(sales) OVER ()) AS total_avg, b.avg_time_to_fill
FROM table a
WHERE (date > '01/01/2023')
JOIN CTE b
ON b.CTE_location_id = a.location_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything more complicated that using two window functions:

```
select distinct Location, 
    Avg(sales) over(partition by location) AvgSales,
    Avg(sales) over() DatasetAvg
from t
order by Location;
```